# QGIS server won't return JSON(P)

Tags: qgis, wfs, json

We set up a QGIS server and are using QGIS to connect to a WFS layer. Everything is working fine within the desktop application. Then we use qgis2leaf to generate a html/js web map. That all works fine, except when I use the WFS layer. For some reason I am getting the Unexpected token < error, as can be seen here (http://qgis.webmuni.com/export).

So basically what I think is happening is that the call that is made is (http://qgis.webmuni.com/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=zones2&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:processJSON) and it expects it to return JSON, but the server is returning XML.

I don't know why the server wont return JSON(P) and I am not sure if there is something I am doing wrong or if we need to configure the server in some way to enable JSON capabilities.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type check application/json + application/javascript

Comment: I tried changing contentType : 'application/json', to contentType : 'application/javascript'.. no change.. Shouldnt the request be returning JSON instead of XML? This request (http://qgis.webmuni.com/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=zones2&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:processJSON)

Answer (score 2):

Got it figured out:

qgis2leaf used outputFormat=text/javascript, which for some reason was returning XML, but changing that to outputFormat=GeoJSON worked for me with QGIS server.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: I wrote the WFS code for qgis2leaf, and I was using Geoserver, so that explains it. I don't know of a way to detect whether a QGIS WFS layer is Geoserver or something else such as QGIS Server. If we could work that out, I could fix this problem.

Comment: By the way, qgis2leaf is no longer being developed. Try qgis2web instead.